# Demonstrating the contents of an array but it populates wrong numbers

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm new to C#, and I am supposed to be **demonstrating creating arrays and processing the contents of the arrays**. Whenever I press calculate I get the same numbers every time. I am not sure what I am missing? I changed double to decimals thinking that might help change things, but no matter what I try to fix it still comes up the same. Any help in this is appreciated. I also had to save a .txt file into the same folder as the bin/debug for this project. **Im instructed that this is supposed to read the files content into the array of double or decimal.** the folder just has a few numbers with decimals (1260.07, etc)

heres the code I have so far.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsAppAssignment6
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void analyzeBtn_Click(object sender,System.EventArgs e)
        {       
            string file = "Sales.txt";
            string salesValue;
            Decimal[] sales = new decimal[7];
            int count = 0;
            decimal maxSales = Decimal.MinValue;
            decimal minSales = Decimal.MaxValue;
            decimal totalSales = 0;
            try
            { 
                StreamReader dataStream = new StreamReader(file);

                salesValue = dataStream.ReadLine();

                var total = sales.Sum();

                var average = sales.Average();

                var high = sales.Max();

                var low = sales.Min();

                while (salesValue != null)
                {
                    sales[count] = Convert.ToDecimal(salesValue);
                    totalSales += sales[count];

                    if (sales[count] > maxSales)
                        maxSales = sales[count];

                    if (sales[count] < minSales)
                        minSales = sales[count];


                    count++;

                    salesValue = dataStream.ReadLine();
                }

                dataStream.Close();
            
                for (int item = 0; item < 7; item++)
                    salesListBox.Items.Add(sales[item]);

          
                totalLbl.Text = totalSales + "";
                avgLabel.Text = totalSales  + "";
                highSalesLabel.Text = maxSales + "";
                smallSalesLabel.Text = minSales + "";
   

         
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        private void label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void exitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}'''
```

[Heres what populates every time.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOgZC.png)

Comment: `sales = new decimal[7];` creates an array with 7 zeroes in it. You then get a Sum/ Average/ Min/ Max of this set of zeroes, which will all be zero. You need to do those things _after_ you put the values into the array :)

Comment: Oh and secondly your while loop never runs - i.e. salesValue is always null (presumably giving it the wrong file). It's the only way that your max/ min files can still be on their initial values after it. Definitely have a go at learning how to use the debugger so you can step through the code and see the value of things as it goes.

Comment: thank you! I will try this. I didnt realize that I needed to do that after the array! it makes sense now that someone has spelled it out for me.

Comment: @LukeBriggs Actually, he is putting values into it, that's what the first part of the while loop is doing, he overwrites the 0 at the index with the parsed value and assigns the other values appropriately, see my answer for more details.

Comment: and running the debugger is actually kind of confusing in visual studio for me. It tells me when I have errors, but doesnt seem to show any kind of resolution to the problem? unless I am overlooking something. it's my 2nd week in this world of C# and at first I was able to seamlessly understand its language, but soon after got completely caught off guard as to what the heck is going on. Thanks again for your response!

Comment: @ZXYNINE If you look at the screengrab, it definitely gets to the `.Text` lines as the text boxes have values in them. I.e. there isn't an exception happening. Because the `minSales` and `maxSales` values are both on their MinValue/MaxValue respectively, neither of them are being set at all - the only way that is possible is if the very first `salesValue` is null.

Comment: @binaryBiscuit the debugger doesn't know what your goal is so all it can really do is show you what values are being set. For example in your case, when the debugger gets to the first `salesValue = dataStream.ReadLine();`, you'd see that salesValue is probably still `null` which is not what you'd want to happen. Then from there you can find out why that would be null (and in the ms docs, it's because it's at the end of the file - i.e. the file it is reading is actually empty).

Comment: Show us the contents of Sales.txt

Comment: contents of the file are the following1245.67
1189.55
1098.72
1456.88
2109.34
1987.555
1872.36

Comment: Stil having issues via an error i cant seem to figure out.    'StringReader  dataStream = new StringReader(SalesTxt);' the (SalesTxt) is saying it doesnt exist?

Answer (score -1):

The problem I think is with your error handling or the format of your document. Convert will actually throw an exception which will kill your entire loop if it cannot parse the current line. Say you had a simple line break in your file that created an empty line, you would try to parse it, an error is thrown, your code does nothing after it. Since I didnt have your file and I really do not feel like using visual studio instead of vscode, I replaced your streamreader with a stringreader (reads a string instead of a file but almost exactly the same) and i replaced the form with simple console writes. Outside of those changes, I gave myself some extra room in the array size since it was throwing exceptions and i wrapped the inside of the while loop in a try catch for format exceptions which is what Convert throws. After I made those changes, the outputs all worked properly. If you still dont see the values, then it is a problem with how you are using windows forms not your codes logic itself.

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    analyzeBtn_Click();
}


public static string SalesTxt = @"
1260.07
4002.52
267.21
15773.223
66655.2
555.0
7322
";





 private static void analyzeBtn_Click()
    {       
        string salesValue;
        Decimal[] sales = new decimal[8];
        int count = 0;
        decimal maxSales = Decimal.MinValue;
        decimal minSales = Decimal.MaxValue;
        decimal totalSales = 0;
        try
        { 
            StringReader  dataStream = new StringReader(SalesTxt);

            salesValue = dataStream.ReadLine();

            var total = sales.Sum();
            var average = sales.Average();
            var high = sales.Max();
            var low = sales.Min();

            while (salesValue != null)
            {
                try {
                    sales[count] = Convert.ToDecimal(salesValue);
                    
                    totalSales += sales[count];

                    if (sales[count] > maxSales)
                        maxSales = sales[count];

                    if (sales[count] < minSales)
                        minSales = sales[count];


                    count++;
                } catch (FormatException) {Console.WriteLine("\tException: '"+ salesValue + "'"); }

                salesValue = dataStream.ReadLine();
            }

            dataStream.Close();
        
            string listItems = string.Join(",\n", sales);
            
      
            Console.WriteLine(listItems);
            Console.WriteLine(totalSales);
            Console.WriteLine(maxSales);
            Console.WriteLine(minSales);
     
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
Hello World
    Exception: ''
    Exception: '    '
1260.07,
4002.52,
267.21,
15773.223,
66655.2,
555.0,
7322,
0
95835.223
66655.2
267.21
```

EDIT:

In light of discussion, I have moved the string into a file with the appropriate name and used StreamReader just as you originally did. Using the same code as above just slightly modified, I was still able to get the correct output. [image]

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I feel like a fool.   "Convert will actually throw an exception which will kill your entire loop if it cannot parse the current line. Say you had a simple line break in your file that created an empty line, you would try to parse it, an error is thrown, your code does nothing after it." i had no idea.... guess i need to hit the books again. Thanks again!

Comment: @binaryBiscuit We all have to start somewhere, surprisingly all of your total, max, and min calculations gave the correct answer which you apparently couldn't have tested as you only saw 0's in your form, so thats pretty solid. If you get it working, dont forget to mark my response as the answer as it helps others in a similar situation! ^.^

Comment: If it threw an exception on the convert line, a message box would've appeared as it was already in a try/catch, and secondly, the text fields would not have been populated as they are in the screenshot. This definitely isn't the root cause of the problem.

Comment: @LukeBriggs thats true, I was about to correct myself, the error is clearly in him trying to read the file.

Comment: @ZXYNINE Correct, `presumably giving it the wrong file` as was said in the comments :) If you're going to start an answer by calling someone else wrong, make sure you're right dude lol

Comment: @LukeBriggs To be clear, you were wrong on what I said, I was posting my answer only in response to what you said in the first comment dude. 

"You then get a Sum/ Average/ Min/ Max of this set of zeroes, which will all be zero. You need to do those things after you put the values into the array"

Is wrong as the value at sales[count] is set on the very first line of his while loop. As my code exemplifies, his code works if the data can actually be read.

Comment: @ZXYNINE Definitely not wrong: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBION.png

Comment: @binaryBiscuit I added to my answer with another test I ran, you will see it still worked using a file instead of just a string, so you need to make sure the file it is reading has the correct name, is in the same directory as the code, and definitely has data in it.

Comment: @ZXYNINE Please explain how those Sum/ Average/ Min/ Max linq calls are able to use the data set by the while loop after them..

Comment: @LukeBriggs Okay, I do see what you are referring to, but if you look, those variables are not actually ever used at all. They are replaced by his maxSales and minSales and totalSales. The loop will run and give correct values as I have tested it in two different environments. 

They can be removed with no changes to the output. You are correct that they will have no value, but them having value means nothing to the code as it currently stands.

Comment: Yes but the fact that they're there at all suggests a misunderstanding of code flow. They are in the wrong place, as the comment said. His loop is not running, likely because he is using the wrong file, as the other comment said. Your answer still starts with "contrary to what was said in the comments" - which is wrong and somewhat unfair.

Comment: @LukeBriggs As he said, He changed the data type to a decimal and clearly when he did he added the variables that are being used currently, we cannot know how his file looked before he made changes as that code represents leftover which should be removed entirely, it is unfair to say that he has a "misunderstanding of code flow" based on scrap code that isn't being used that is a direct result of debugging. As for the comment, I did have a misunderstanding as again, the scrap code is just that and so I never even saw that to know you were referring to that. I will Change my Answer.

Comment: @ZXYNINE "never even saw it" - Can quite clearly see it at the bottom of your own screenshot. You don't know it's unused until you've read the whole method (particularly as your IDE isn't greying them out). I spotted it straight away whilst reading down the code, thus that comment came first.

Comment: @LukeBriggs At this point this discussion is meaningless and does not help this guy in any way, if you want to continue, start a chat and we can have a back and fourth if you so please as to how i solve problems. I followed the main code that influences the output, as that is all that matters, those variables are only referenced once where they are initialised and thusly I did not see them in the actual functional sections of the code and so I did not see them (brain ignored them). I follow variables by signature using vs code or ctrl f if i need to, the REPL was just to run it.

Comment: You started your answer by directly contradicting someone else who was also just trying to help. Trying to help people is great, but now we have 2 unhappy people because of that. I would suggest just deleting this answer as it doesn't answer to the root of his problem anyway.

Comment: Gentlemen, I apologize that I was the leading contributor to initiating this heated debate. Although heated, very informative nonetheless. Thank you both! :)